# How to prevent windows server from locking?

Tags: windows, windows-server, lock-screen, windows-server-2019

I want to prevent a Windows server from ever locking. I'm using AWS EC2 and I am connecting with RDP.

I tried [autologin](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autologon) but it is obviously not working.

I've a script which is running in the background, drawing on the screen and in the time I've been disconnected nothing was drawn.

I'm using Windows Server 2019.

Answer (score 1):

You can control this behavior via GPO.

gpedit.msc -> Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\System\Power Management\Video and Display Settings -> "Turn Off the Diplay (Plugged in)

Enable that GPO, and set the seconds to value to "0".

https://redmondmag.com/articles/2016/04/25/disable-windows-server-auto-lock-feature.aspx

It isn't recommended though, from a security point of view.